# The existence of linear function which smaller than convex functions.

Tags: stochastic-calculus, jensen-inequality

I am trying to prove the Jensen's inequality for conditional expectations.

It is done if we can show that:

With a convex function $\phi$ bounded from below, there exists a linear function $h(x)=ax+b$ such that:

$\phi(x)\geq h(x)$.

So, how to prove the existence of $h(x)$?

Comment: What are your precise assumptions on $\phi$?

Comment: $\phi$ is bounded below, I added this assumption.

Comment: If a function $\phi$ is bounded from below by $b$ then clearly the "linear" function $h(x) = b$ satisfies $\phi(x) \geq h(x)$ for all $x$, and that does not get you Jensen's inequality.

Comment: I mean a class of functions. From this we can have: $E(\phi(x))\geq h(E(x))$
So, $E(\phi(x)) \geq sup (h(E(x))) = \phi(E(x))$